# How to get word by word from a string?

Tags: python

For the purpose of sentiment analysis I want to analyse each word in a sentence. I want to store each word in a variable and then process it. I use the following code and i got an error message saying :

> Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

```
line = ' hello this is a test sentence'
   while line:
       line=line.split(' ')
       print '\n'
```

What is the solution for above problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what happens in your code:

1. `line = "..."` - line is a string
2. `while line:` - start looping, as non-empty string evaluates to `True`
3. `line = line.split(" ")` - `split` `line` by spaces, `line` is now a list
4. `print '\n'` - print a newline character
5. `while line:` - non-empty list evaluates `True`, so loop again
6. `line = line.split(" ")` - `line` is a list, hence `AttributeError`

I am not sure why you are using a `while` loop here, you probably want:

```
for word in line.split(" "):
    print word
    # ... process word
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is actually when the loop hits its second iteration line is no longer a string. and so the logic says is object line not None if yes, run split on it. However at this point line is now a list.
what you really want is

```
   line = 'hello this is a sentance'
    words = line.split()
    for w in words:
        print w
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

```
string.split(' ') ?

>>> a="1.MATCHES$$TEXT$$STRING"
>>> a.split("$$TEXT$$")
['1.MATCHES', 'STRING']

>>> a="2.MATCHES $$TEXT$$ STRING"
>>> a.split("$$TEXT$$")
['2.MATCHES ', ' STRING']
```

and:

```
>>> [x.strip() for x in "2.MATCHES $$TEXT$$ STRING".split("$$TEXT$$")]
['2.MATCHES', 'STRING']
```

so whats nice is you don't have to loop, you have have to assign it and use it.

```
a="my;string;here"
a = a.split(";")
for w in a:
    print w
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string once: `wordList = line.split()`
And use the wordList to iterate over:

```
for x in wordList:
    doWork...
```

p.s.: I don't quite get why you would print a newline character in each iteration of the loop.